# How to detect if a typescript function is async

Tags: typescript

I write a function to handle exceptions thrown from async functions like:

```
protected safeAsync(f : e.RequestHandler) : e.RequestHandler {
    /* how to detect if `f` is an async function here ?? */
    const binded = f.bind(this);
    return async function innerCall(req : e.Request, res : e.Response, next : Function) {
        try {
            return await binded(req, res, next);
        } catch (err) {
            log.debug(err);
            return next(err);
        }
    }
}
```

The parameter `f` is supposed be an async function, such as

```
public async signupPost(req : e.Request, res : e.Response, next : Function) {/*...*/}
```

My question is:

In `safeAsync`, is there a way to detect if `f` is an async function, so I can log unexpected call to `safeAsync` ?

Comment: I believe it shouldn't matter if `f` has an `async` keyword or not. You should still be able to await it as long as it returns a promise.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since this is a **runtime** check the question you should be asking is whether or not JavaScript provides a way to check if a function is async. The answer is no, there is no fool proof way to tell if a function is async or not, it could even be both.

Answer (score 0):

You can force it to be async just be doing `Promise.resolve(f())`, function "f" may return a promise or not but resolve will make it a promise anyway.